# Define $f(x)=x^3$ for all $x$. Verify the the $\epsilon - \delta$ criterion at each point $x_0$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Following Clayton's advice, for $\epsilon>0$, we must find a $\delta>0$ such that $|x^3-x_0^3|<\epsilon$ if $|x-x_0|<\delta$.

$|x^3-x_0^3|=|x-x_0||x^2+x_0x+x_0^2|<\epsilon$

I'm still working though.

Comment: Go back to what the $\epsilon-\delta$ actually is and show us what you know and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** A standard technique to prove something for all $x\in\Bbb R$ is to first let it be arbitrary; i.e., let $x_0\in\Bbb R$. Prove the function is continuous at $x_0$ and then argue since $x_0$ was arbitrary, it must be true for every $x\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Pick some $x_0$. Then try to bound $|f(x)-f(x_0)| = |x^3-x_0^3|$.

Note that since $x_0$ is a zero of the polynomial $x \mapsto x^3-x_0^3$, we must have  $(x-x_0)$ as a divisor of $x^3-x_0^3$.  That is, you can write $x^3-x_0^3=(x-x_0)p(x)$ for some polynomial $p$.

This should help in obtaining the required bounds.

Comment: But how do I find the bounds now that I'm not close to a single point (usually I pick an interval around the point of interest and use the max to create an upper bound for the inequality)?

Comment: You are close to a single point $x_0$. When you obtain a formula for $\delta$, it must have $x_0$ in there, so while you do not have an actual number, you have an expression involving $x_0$. For example, if I have an expression $x^2$ and I stipulate that $|x-x_0|<1$, then I can state that $x^2 \le (|x_0|+1)^2$, that is $x^2$ is bounded above by a 'known' quantity (even though $x_0$ is an arbitrary number).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Note that $$x^3-x_0^3=(x-x_0)(x^2+xx_0+x_0^2)$$ and $$\begin{align}x^2+xx_0+x_0^2 &= x^2-2xx_0+x_0^2+3xx_0\\ &= (x-x_0)^2+3xx_0\\ &= (x-x_0)^2+3xx_0-3x_0^2+3x_0^2\\ &= (x-x_0)^2+3x_0(x-x_0)+3x_0^2.\end{align}$$ Use these, together with triangle inequality, to rewrite $|x^3-x_0^3|$ in terms of $|x_0|$ and $|x-x_0|,$ and your choice of $\delta$ (given $\epsilon$) should become clearer.

Comment: I just end up with $|x^3-x_0^3|\le |x-x_0|(|(x-x_0)^2|+3|x_0(x-x_0)|+3|x_0^2|)<\epsilon$. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to come up with a $\delta$.

Comment: If you rewrite it as $$|x-x_0|\bigl(|x-x_0|^2+3|x_0||x-x_0|+3|x_0|^2\bigr),\tag{1}$$ then for any $c>0,$ if we have $|x-x_0|<\min\{1,c\},$ it follows that the quantity in $(1)$ is less than or equal to $$c\bigl(1+3|x_0|+3|x_0|^2\bigr).\tag{2}$$ By choosing a small enough $c$ so that the quantity in $(2)$ is less than $\epsilon$, then all that is left is to put $\delta=\min\{1,c\},$ and we're done. It's a bit of a slick trick that often comes in handy. Can you find an appropriate $c$?